# In R (and when installing ROracle package), how do I set OCI_LIB64?

Tags: r, oracle, oracle-call-interface, instantclient, roracle

In R (and when installing ROracle package), how do I set OCI_LIB64? I've downloaded Oracle Instant Client and have pointed the wd and the OCI_LIB64 to that. I have Windows 10 Enterprise. It's RStudio version 1.1.463 and R version 3.4.3.

I tried the following:

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\sriley03\\Documents\\')   # set to path of download (remember to escape slashes ie:  c:\\users\\etc..)
set OCI_LIB64=C:\Users\sriley03\Documents\instantclient_19_3
install.packages('ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz', repos = NULL)
```

but I get the following output and errors:

```
> setwd('C:\\Users\\sriley03\\Documents\\')   # set to path of download (remember to escape slashes ie:  c:\\users\\etc..)
The working directory was changed to C:/Users/sriley03/Documents/ inside a notebook chunk. The working directory will be reset when the chunk is finished running. Use the knitr root.dir option in the setup chunk to change the working directory for notebook chunks.Error: unexpected symbol in "set OCI_LIB64"

> setwd('C:\\Users\\sriley03\\Documents\\instantclient_19_3')   # set to path of download (remember to escape slashes ie:  c:\\users\\etc..)
The working directory was changed to C:/Users/sriley03/Documents/instantclient_19_3 inside a notebook chunk. The working directory will be reset when the chunk is finished running. Use the knitr root.dir option in the setup chunk to change the working directory for notebook chunks.> set OCI_LIB64=C:\Users\sriley03\Documents\instantclient_19_3
Error: unexpected symbol in "set OCI_LIB64"

> install.packages('ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz', repos = NULL)
Warning: invalid package 'ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library" "ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

What can I do so that I can set OCI_LIB64 properly so that I can install ROracle?

Thanks!

UPDATE (8_28_19):

I've set the OCI_LIB64 and the OCI_INC to the correct paths

```
Sys.setenv(OCI_LIB64="C:\\Users\\sriley03\\Documents\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_19_3")
Sys.setenv(OCI_INC="C:\\Users\\sriley03\\Documents\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_19_3")
```

But now I get the following response (even though all the required headers are in that file):

```
* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Oracle Client Shared Library 64-bit - 19.3.0.0.0 Operating in Instant Client mode.
found Oracle Client C:\Users\sriley03\Documents\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_19_3
found Oracle Client include C:\Users\sriley03\Documents\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_19_3
ERROR: cannot find Oracle Client include headers in C:\Users\sriley03\Documents\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_19_3.
       Please set OCI_INC to correct location.
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 1
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/ROracle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library" C:\Users\sriley03\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUfabz/downloaded_packages/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz' had status 1
```

Comment: The command (if you want to try) as joran hinted would be `Sys.setenv(OCI_LIB64="C:/Users/sriley03/Documents/instantclient_19_3")`. (I use forward-slashes -- even on win10 -- because I feel backslashes get ugly, no other reason.)

Comment: The *"no packages specified"* can happen if the file is not found. With all of the `knitr` warnings about working directories going on there, I wonder if that might be a path issue ... are you able to use an absolute path? Perhaps instead of `setwd` and such, you can use `withr::with_dir("c:/Users/.../instantclient_19_3", install.packages(...))`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here is how I fixed it.

```
Sys.setenv(OCI_INC="C:\\Oracle\\OraClient64_11204\\oci\\include")
Sys.setenv(OCI_LIB64="C:\\Oracle\\OraClient64_11204\\BIN")
```

Remember to use two backslash(es) for Windows.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the SDK Package from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) and unzip it in your instant client folder.

set the environment variable OCI_INC to the 'include' folder located in your instant client folder: ..."instantclient_xx_x\sdk\include"

Then, reinstall the packages.

If you still get a failure error, try to copy all files from sdk\include folder to your R include folder, then try again

Comment: Can you elaborate on "set the OCI_INC to ..."instantclient_xx_x\sdk\include"? Searching for set OCI_INC led to this page. There will likely be others trying to figure out how to do that with little Oracle setup experience.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to answer, the OCI_INC is an environment variable, you can check details about ROracle setup at this medium post by Jasmin Fluri:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-roracle-on-windows-10-144b0b923dac